# Append some html to redirected site php

Tags: php, html, redirect, append

Let's say I have a script, that redirects to another page based on your type of input.
Now that site you're redirected to already has a long query string. So what I'd like to do,
is append some html code to the end of the site without actualy sending GET or POST requests, let's say something like:

```
<?php
header("Location: redirectedsite.php");
//send extre html img for example
$html="<html><img scr='img.jpg'></img></html>";
?>
```

Is that even possible? I know about sessions and cookies, but I'd like to see if there are any alternatives.

Comment: As I said, I could easily use session, cookie, post/get, but that's easy :P
I'd like to do that for educational purposes :P
So you can't do that with php, how about JS, or any other way?

Answer (score 1):

Once the browser redirects to the other site, the body of your page gets ignored and ONLY the other site gets shown to the user.

So, unfortunately, what you want is not possible; if the redirected site is under your control you could conditionally add more contents based on a `GET` parameter, but it would still not work in the way you've described.

In fact, this would probably be a security nightmare if you could append HTML to any another website.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible in that manner no, sorry. If you control the destination site you could, as you say, set a session variable that would prompt the destination page to append the code, but there is no way to do it directly in the way you want. And neither option is possible if you don't control the destination.

Answer (score 0):

Nope. When you do a header redirect, the browser will go there  straight away. You can't add some HTML in between.

You would have to do that on the target page, or show a proper HTML page that then uses another kind of redirect (using [the legacy `<META>`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh) or JavaScript, or a combination of both along with a link that can be clicked manually).

Answer (score 0):

Aside from appending it as a query parameter, or using session variables, you can't do this. Is there any particular reason you don't want to use sessions?